# Fluxible createStore module not found/cannot be resolved?

Tags: reactjs, fluxible

I am getting an error in fluxible when attempting to create a store, specifically UserStore:

Error: Cannot find module 'fluxible-app/utils/createStore'

How do I get around this?

The project/code I am working with is the following:

https://github.com/jaxoncreed/the-next-facebook/blob/76b2651f7d04c3df569dfcf5f1460ed82678b807/stores/UserStore.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have both `fluxible-app` and `fluxible` installed at the same time. `fluxible-app` is the predecessor to `fluxible` and is no longer necessary.

You can get get `createStore` via `require('fluxible/addons/createStore')` instead of from fluxible-app.

See http://fluxible.io/addons/createStore.html